# Verification of export parallelization

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When it comes to export, we have the following property options which affect concurrency of the export either to storage directly or to external table (documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage)):-

```
distribution
distributed
spread
concurrency
query_fanout_nodes_percent
```

Say, I tweak these options and increase/decrease concurrency based on shards or nodes, is there any Kusto command that will allow me to exactly see how many of these parallel threads of export (whether it's based on per_shard or per_node or some percent) are running? The command `.show operation details` doesn't show these details , it just shows how many separate export commands are issued by client and not the related parallelization details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands now, there is no additional information that the system will provide regarding the threads used in the export operation in the same way that this information is not available for queries.

Can you add to your question the benefit of having such information? Is it to track the progress of the command? In any case, if this is something that you feel is missing from the service please open a new item or vote for an existing item in the [Azure Data Explorer user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer)

Comment: the benefit would be for tracking and also for clear understanding of how various options affect concurrency

Comment: ideally, the queries duration, the queries concurrency and other metrics such CPU, stage latency (for ingestion) should provide the information you need.